# rails s LoadError: cannot load such file -- refile/simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

- I am having an issue with when I run rails s. I am working on a legacy application and attempting to upgrade to the latest versions of rails and ruby. Current application is using ruby 2.5.0 and rails 5.2.8.  The issue is centered around the following:

`/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in require': cannot load such file -- refile/simple_form (LoadError)`

- When I run `bundle install` it is successful rendering the following results:

Bundle complete! 43 Gemfile dependencies, 150 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
1 installed gem you directly depend on is looking for funding.
Run `bundle fund` for details

- When I run `bundle fund` I get the following:

`cancancan (3.3.0) Funding: https://github.com/sponsors/coorasse`

- I then at `cancancan (3.3.0)` to my gemfile and run `bundle install` again which results successfully. I try to run `rails s` and I continue to get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
  I even tried to set the `gem refile` to `gem 'refile', require: ['refile/rails', 'refile/simple_form']`. This does not make a difference.

***Current Error after running rails s***

```
user@user-2 project_001 % rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.8 application starting in development 
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    61: from bin/rails:4:in <main>'
    60: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in require'
    59: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in require'
    58: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in <top (required)>'
    57: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in invoke'
    56: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in perform'
    55: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in dispatch'
    54: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in invoke_command'
    53: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run'
    52: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in perform'
    51: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in tap'
    50: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in block in perform'
    49: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in start'
    48: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in log_to_stdout'
    47: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in wrapped_app'
    46: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in app'
    45: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in app'
    44: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in build_app_and_options_from_config'
    43: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in parse_file'
    42: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in load_file'
    41: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in new_from_string'
    40: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in eval'
    39: from config.ru:3:in block in <main>'
    38: from config.ru:3:in require_relative'
    37: from /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/Alaska-Project/project_001/config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
    36: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in initialize!'
    35: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in run_initializers'
    34: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in tsort_each'
    33: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in tsort_each'
    32: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in each_strongly_connected_component'
    31: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in call'
    30: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in each'
    29: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    28: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    27: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in call'
    26: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in tsort_each_child'
    25: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in each'
    24: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    23: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    22: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    21: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    20: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in block in tsort_each'
    19: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in block in run_initializers'
    18: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in run'
    17: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in instance_exec'
    16: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in block in <class:Engine>'
    15: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in each'
    14: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    13: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:662:in load_config_initializer'
    12: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in instrument'
    11: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:663:in block in load_config_initializer'
    10: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in load'
     9: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in load_dependency'
     8: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in block in load'
     7: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in load'
     6: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in load'
     5: from /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/Alaska-Project/project_001/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in <top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in require'
     3: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in load_dependency'
     2: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in block in require'
     1: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in require'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in require': cannot load such file -- refile/simple_form (LoadError)
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'next_rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
# gem 'pg', '0.18.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.12.6'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.2'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis'#, '~> 4.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.11.1', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]

end

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]


gem "haml"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-github"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", '~> 0.8.0'
gem "omniauth-openid"
gem "google-api-client"
gem 'cancancan', '~> 3.3'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'friendly_id'#, '~> 5.0.0'
# gem 'ransack'
# gem 'rdiscount', require: 'tilt/rdiscount'
gem 'ruby_identicon'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem "refile", require: "refile/rails"
# gem "refile-mini_magick"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'chartkick', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.2' #gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'faker'
# gem 'skylight'

gem 'bundler', '>= 2.0.0.pre.3' #'~> 2.3'#, '>= 2.0.0.pre3' #, 
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.1.0'
gem "font-awesome-rails"

# bring back removed support for respond_with
# gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  # gem 'puma'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'

  # Listens to file modifications and notifies you about the changes
  gem 'listen' #, '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
    
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

  # gem 'guard'
  # gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'better_errors'
  # gem 'binding_of_caller'
  # gem 'quiet_assets'
  # gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara' #, '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
   
  # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

ruby "2.5.0"
```

**simple_form.rb**

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
require 'refile/simple_form'

SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Wrappers are used by the form builder to generate a
  # complete input. You can remove any component from the
  # wrapper, change the order or even add your own to the
  # stack. The options given below are used to wrap the
  # whole input.
  config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
    hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
    ## Extensions enabled by default
    # Any of these extensions can be disabled for a
    # given input by passing: `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => false`.
    # You can make any of these extensions optional by
    # renaming `b.use` to `b.optional`.

    # Determines whether to use HTML5 (:email, :url, ...)
    # and required attributes
    b.use :html5

    # Calculates placeholders automatically from I18n
    # You can also pass a string as f.input placeholder: "Placeholder"
    b.use :placeholder

    ## Optional extensions
    # They are disabled unless you pass `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => true`
    # to the input. If so, they will retrieve the values from the model
    # if any exists. If you want to enable any of those
    # extensions by default, you can change `b.optional` to `b.use`.

    # Calculates maxlength from length validations for string inputs
    b.optional :maxlength

    # Calculates pattern from format validations for string inputs
    b.optional :pattern

    # Calculates min and max from length validations for numeric inputs
    b.optional :min_max

    # Calculates readonly automatically from readonly attributes
    b.optional :readonly

    ## Inputs
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }

    ## full_messages_for
    # If you want to display the full error message for the attribute, you can
    # use the component :full_error, like:
    #
    # b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end

  # The default wrapper to be used by the FormBuilder.
  config.default_wrapper = :default

  # Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
  # Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
  #   inline: input + label
  #   nested: label > input
  config.boolean_style = :nested

  # Default class for buttons
  config.button_class = 'btn'

  # Method used to tidy up errors. Specify any Rails Array method.
  # :first lists the first message for each field.
  # Use :to_sentence to list all errors for each field.
  # config.error_method = :first

  # Default tag used for error notification helper.
  config.error_notification_tag = :div

  # CSS class to add for error notification helper.
  config.error_notification_class = 'error_notification'

  # ID to add for error notification helper.
  # config.error_notification_id = nil

  # Series of attempts to detect a default label method for collection.
  # config.collection_label_methods = [ :to_label, :name, :title, :to_s ]

  # Series of attempts to detect a default value method for collection.
  # config.collection_value_methods = [ :id, :to_s ]

  # You can wrap a collection of radio/check boxes in a pre-defined tag, defaulting to none.
  # config.collection_wrapper_tag = nil

  # You can define the class to use on all collection wrappers. Defaulting to none.
  # config.collection_wrapper_class = nil

  # You can wrap each item in a collection of radio/check boxes with a tag,
  # defaulting to :span.
  # config.item_wrapper_tag = :span

  # You can define a class to use in all item wrappers. Defaulting to none.
  # config.item_wrapper_class = nil

  # How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.
  # config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{required} #{label}" }

  # You can define the class to use on all labels. Default is nil.
  # config.label_class = nil

  # You can define the default class to be used on forms. Can be overriden
  # with `html: { :class }`. Defaulting to none.
  # config.default_form_class = nil

  # You can define which elements should obtain additional classes
  # config.generate_additional_classes_for = [:wrapper, :label, :input]

  # Whether attributes are required by default (or not). Default is true.
  # config.required_by_default = true

  # Tell browsers whether to use the native HTML5 validations (novalidate form option).
  # These validations are enabled in SimpleForm's internal config but disabled by default
  # in this configuration, which is recommended due to some quirks from different browsers.
  # To stop SimpleForm from generating the novalidate option, enabling the HTML5 validations,
  # change this configuration to true.
  config.browser_validations = false

  # Collection of methods to detect if a file type was given.
  # config.file_methods = [ :mounted_as, :file?, :public_filename ]

  # Custom mappings for input types. This should be a hash containing a regexp
  # to match as key, and the input type that will be used when the field name
  # matches the regexp as value.
  # config.input_mappings = { /count/ => :integer }

  # Custom wrappers for input types. This should be a hash containing an input
  # type as key and the wrapper that will be used for all inputs with specified type.
  # config.wrapper_mappings = { string: :prepend }

  # Namespaces where SimpleForm should look for custom input classes that
  # override default inputs.
  # config.custom_inputs_namespaces << "CustomInputs"

  # Default priority for time_zone inputs.
  # config.time_zone_priority = nil

  # Default priority for country inputs.
  # config.country_priority = nil

  # When false, do not use translations for labels.
  # config.translate_labels = true

  # Automatically discover new inputs in Rails' autoload path.
  # config.inputs_discovery = true

  # Cache SimpleForm inputs discovery
  # config.cache_discovery = !Rails.env.development?

  # Default class for inputs
  # config.input_class = nil

  # Define the default class of the input wrapper of the boolean input.
  config.boolean_label_class = 'checkbox'

  # Defines if the default input wrapper class should be included in radio
  # collection wrappers.
  # config.include_default_input_wrapper_class = true

  # Defines which i18n scope will be used in Simple Form.
  # config.i18n_scope = 'simple_form'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The gem for the missing resource is commented out in your Gemfile:

```
# gem 'refile', require:  'refile/simple_form'
```

Also, make sure that the version of refile being installed is at least 0.6.0 (i.e., the version where simple_form support was introduced.) Sometimes conflicts cause bundler to go back to refile 0.3.0.

Comment: I removed it from my Gemfile. It should not be there. The issue persists

Comment: I think you want the line `gem 'refile', require:  'refile/simple_form'` to be in your Gemfile. That's the package that `simple_form.rb` is looking for. Also, which version of refile is getting installed?

Comment: The current refile version is 0.3.0. I also added the following in my Gemfile `gem 'refile', require:  'refile/simple_form' ` @brtrick

Comment: You will need to upgrade refile to at least 0.6.0 (current gem is 0.6.2; if you download directly from github, it is 0.7.0) since that is where the SimpleForm support was introduced. You can install the latest version from github with `gem "refile", github: 'refile/refile', require: "refile/simple_form"`. Hopefully that will address whatever conflicts caused bundler to revert to 0.3.0.

Comment: I have upgraded refile to at least 0.6.0. I will add `gem "refile", github: 'refile/refile', require: "refile/simple_form"` to see if it makes a difference.